# How to set password in LocalDataSource

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to create a LocalDataSource with the intellij plugin sdk. But i can't figure out how to set the password of a DataSource.

Example:

```java
String uniqueName = DbUtil.generateUniqueDataSourceName(project, "Test");
LocalDataSource dataSource = LocalDataSource.create(uniqueName, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", uniqueName);
dataSource.setUsername("testuser");
dataSource.setPasswordStorage(LocalDataSource.Storage.PERSIST);

LocalDataSourceManager.getInstance(project).addDataSource(dataSource);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,

```
 private void addPasswordToLocalDataSource(@NotNull LocalDataSource ds, @Nullable String password) {

    ds.setPasswordStorage(LocalDataSource.Storage.PERSIST);
    DatabaseCredentials.getInstance().setPassword(ds, password == null ? null : new OneTimeString(password));
    ds.resolveDriver();
    ds.ensureDriverConfigured();
    DataSourceStorage.getProjectStorage(myProject).addDataSource(ds);
  }
```

It seems also you can do it as part of the constructor,

```
LocalDataSource ds = new LocalDataSource("Test Data Source", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
                         jdbcUrl, "database_user", "sekret");
```

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000690844-Is-it-possible-to-create-a-data-source-via-an-API-